# Can I use Kingston KVR16LS114 ram on HP Probook 4420s?

Tags: memory, ddr3

Can I use Kingston KVR16LS114 ram on HP Probook 4420s? Hp specifications says the laptop supports DDR3 PC3-10600 SDRAM (1333 MHz). However,crucial suggests DDR3 PC3-12800.  Can anyone help me

Comment: Short answer, yes, HP specs the slowest RAM the machine supports, faster RAM that is otherwise identical works fine, the BIOS will automatically adjust the timings accordingly. On a side note, setup lots of these, don't mix RAM speeds (one PC3-10600 and one PC3-12800 DIMM), the motherboard just doesn't like it even though in theory it should work.

Answer (score 0):

As acejavelin as stated,

The Manufacturer has specified DDR3 PC3-10600 1333 MHz SODIMM as the recommended memory. DDR3 PC3-12800 1600 MHz SODIMM will also work. Mixing two speeds 1333 MHz and 1600 MHz will automatically run both at 1333 MHz.

So better to go with 1333 MHz, if you're installing along with the existing (1333 MHz)

Kingston KVR16LS114 is for 4 GB DDR3L (1.35v) PC3L-12800 SODIMM - This is the low voltage than the usual DDR3 (1.5v). It is compatible. It will either run at 1.35v or 1.5v depending on the system.

You can refer think link:
http://www.memorystock.com/memory/HewlettPackardCompaqProBook4420s.html